# Change terraform state lock executor

Tags: terraform

When you do any action, by default, Terraform will create a state lock on the backend with the information of the executor that does the execution in the key **Who.**

Is there any option to change the **MyPCUserName** without changing the user of my machine? Because in some cases, the backend has versioning control and can review all actions, if I want someone else to execute the terraform, it will be tracked.

```
{
  "ID": "id",
  "Operation": "OperationTypeApply",
  "Info": "",
  "Who": "MyPCUserName@ipaddress",
  "Version": "1.5.2",
  "Created": "2023-09-04T15:55:14.783729Z",
  "Path": "somepath/default.tflock"
}
```

I have searched and read the Terraform document but I don't see any information about changing it on the Terraform docs. And I don't have time to read the terraform code :( If there is any configuration for changing it, please help me answer.